# Iframe content is not coming in correct position when calling through script

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am developing a pay per click site. I have developed a script for publishers to show ads. When I put this script in any site, it's coming in a wrong position.

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var campaignid ="9RJNUW1";
var camp_id ="42";
var publisherid ="1350";
var width ="728";
var height ="90";
</script>

<script src="http://www.ayhanetwork.com/en/ad_code.js"></script>
```

But when I put the iframe (which is generated by the script ) is coming in the right position.

**iframe:**

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.ayhanetwork.com/en/code.php?campaignid=9RJNUW1&amp;publisherid=1350&amp;width=728&amp;height=90&amp;camp_id=42" style="width: 748px; height: 110px; border: medium none; clear: both; position: static; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;"></iframe>
```

**Site url** where i placed my code

http://rapidsurfing.net/Gadget/

AND i would like to place my ad like this

I have checked this in `WordPress` site and in a `Codeigniter` site

[image]

And i would like to show my ads Like this

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: can you provide any sample link to see exactly what position is required in webpage?

Comment: This is what i'm getting: http://jsfiddle.net/sR7QV/

Comment: @Khurram Ishaque  http://rapidsurfing.net/Gadget/

Comment: pls confirm the location where the ad should come?

Comment: @Khurram Ishaque I have updated my question.

Comment: according to the style of iframe, you might use position: absolute with top and/or left attribute to set the ad at specific position. So remove position static, left and bottom attributes. If you remove and add top attribute you can move the ad to specific position on page.

Comment: am still not sure, where the ad should appear on the webpage?

Comment: @Khurram Ishaque I have added another screenshot where i would like to show my ad.  i have place my script in side a div which is in that position (given in the image). But ad is showing at the bottom of the page. I have changed iframe style by the way you told. now its showing on the right position of my site with scroll bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to update your code in js file so that the iframe should be appended in the div which has class='ads'.. 
So, you can either use javascript or jquery to do so. And also position absolute should not be used in this case. it should be changed to position: relative.

Comment: class='ads' is wordpress theme class. I can only change to iframe and its content style. Then only it will work in another sites. ie, this script should work in all site not only in the given url

Comment: oh ok. so, isnt there any common place (any div or other element) which can be used to append iframe in it. Because currently iframe is appended in body and repeating it to respective post position seems tedious job.

Comment: See in this example I am appending the iframe in every tag which has class='ads' so it can easily be done like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sR7QV/1/

Comment: @ Khurram Ishaque thanks alot now i change my script to `<div class="ads"><script type="text/javascript">
var campaignid ="9RJNUW1";
var camp_id ="42";
var publisherid ="1350";
var width ="728";
var height ="90";
</script>

<script src="http://www.ayhanetwork.com/en/ad_code.js"></script></div>` and append iframe to class ads

Comment: I have one question too will there be any security problem for adding a div before my script. I have changed my ad class name to a unique one with id and other variables. Because google provide only script (no div or such elements) but their ad displays in the correct place.